# Moving a start date?

Tags: professionalism

Is it unprofessional to move a start date?

I had to decide my start date upon graduation a couple of months ago for a job across the country. Unfortunately, because of the company's moving contractor, my household possessions have a possibility of arriving on my scheduled first day.. Or potentially even later.

Would it be unprofessional of me to move back my start date one week? I was slated to start January 12, but I would like to start January 19 because of the relocation issue.

Thank you in advance, everyone on these boards is always so helpful!

Answer (score 6):

No. It's not unprofessional to move a start date by a week so long as you give a decent heads-up. Your employer should be more than understanding when you explain your reason.

If you end up having to do it more than once, it might raise eyebrows, but your reason is sound.

If your job has you scheduled for initiations and introductions on your first day, you might want to contact whoever is bringing your belongings, and reschedule that instead.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you give adequate notice to anyone who needs it, as long as you keep everyone in the loop, and as long as you are accountable for what you choose to do, you're not likely to go wrong.

1. Keep in close touch with the moving company because you definitely want to pinpoint ASAP the date and time your truck pops up at your front door.
2. Explain your predicament to HR. Tell them that you may have to take a day off with very little notice to bring in your possessions, that you apologize for any inconvenience and that you feel strongly about showing up on the slated date and get onboarded and up and running ASAP.

You don't want to lose up to a week's worth of wages over this b.s. business of a truck that may or may not show up, do you?

And at any rate, you want to get going on your new job, the sooner the better.